# Google Maps API v3 marker with label

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to JS and the Google API and I am trying to make multiple markers each with a label.

From little snippets I've been looking at, there was no simple way to attach a label to a marker in Google Maps API v3. Between Google and stackoverflow searches, everyone used a roundabout procedure that involved creating or editing the label class.

I just want to figure out how to attach a label to each marker in a simple way since I am just starting to learn JS/ Google API v3.

Thanks

EDIT #3:
Okay I finally figured out what was wrong and correctly implemented multiple markers with labels using Lilina's code. Apparently we both defined the var map differently and that itself makes both our codes unable to synchronize well.

I have an additional question now that I am able to use labels for each marker.
I want to be able to hide markers and their labels based on the zoom level that the user is at.

[Google Maps API v3 - Different markers/labels on different zoom levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045562/google-maps-api-v3-different-markers-labels-on-different-zoom-levels)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I can't guarantee it's the simplest, but I like [**MarkerWithLabel**](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/). As shown in [**the basic example**](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/examples/basic.html), CSS styles define the label's appearance and options in the JavaScript define the content and placement.

```
 .labels {
   color: red;
   background-color: white;
   font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
   font-size: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   width: 60px;     
   border: 2px solid black;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

JavaScript:

```
 var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: homeLatLng,
   draggable: true,
   map: map,
   labelContent: "$425K",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
 });
```

The only part that may be confusing is the labelAnchor. By default, the label's top left corner will line up to the marker pushpin's endpoint. Setting the labelAnchor's x-value to half the width defined in the CSS width property will center the label. You can make the label float above the marker pushpin with an anchor point like `new google.maps.Point(22, 50)`.

In case access to the links above are blocked, I copied and pasted the [packed source](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js) of MarkerWithLabel into this [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/36/). I hope JSFiddle is allowed in China :|

Comment: Apparently, I cannot shift all my code to <head>. I am not sure why though, as there are only a few vars as well as an event. The only real main difference I between mine and other working codes is that <head> only contains the variable map, functions, and events. Whereas mine uses a loop for locations.

Comment: Maybe has to do with the order the page gets loaded, for example, if the Javascript gets loaded after the body loads.

Comment: This is a good one..But it takes a lot of time to display the label when the number of markers are huge..Is there any alternate solution to this Problem

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr - As of the 1.1.9 MarkerWithLabel release, it has overlap issues (issue #24) when markers are close together. See it in this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/L2KYQ/2/).

Comment: Anyone knows why this MarkerWithLabel don't take any css style for the font? (like font-size and font-weight he don't take)...

Comment: `MarkwithLable` is unavailable right now, what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

In order to add a label to the map you need to create a custom overlay. The sample at http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html uses a custom class, `Layer`, that inherits from `OverlayView` (which inherits from `MVCObject`) from the Google Maps API. He has a revised version (adds support for visibility, zIndex and a click event) which can be found here: http://blog.mridey.com/2011/05/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html

***The following code is taken directly from Marc Ridey's Blog (the revised link above).***

**Layer class**

```
// Define the overlay, derived from google.maps.OverlayView
function Label(opt_options) {
  // Initialization
  this.setValues(opt_options);


  // Label specific
  var span = this.span_ = document.createElement('span');
  span.style.cssText = 'position: relative; left: -50%; top: -8px; ' +
  'white-space: nowrap; border: 1px solid blue; ' +
  'padding: 2px; background-color: white';


  var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(span);
  div.style.cssText = 'position: absolute; display: none';
};
Label.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;


// Implement onAdd
Label.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var pane = this.getPanes().overlayImage;
  pane.appendChild(this.div_);


  // Ensures the label is redrawn if the text or position is changed.
  var me = this;
  this.listeners_ = [
    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'position_changed', function() { me.draw(); }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'visible_changed', function() { me.draw(); }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'clickable_changed', function() { me.draw(); }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'text_changed', function() { me.draw(); }),
    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'zindex_changed', function() { me.draw(); }),
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function() {
      if (me.get('clickable')) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(me, 'click');
      }
    })
  ];
};

// Implement onRemove
Label.prototype.onRemove = function() {
 this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);

 // Label is removed from the map, stop updating its position/text.
 for (var i = 0, I = this.listeners_.length; i < I; ++i) {
   google.maps.event.removeListener(this.listeners_[i]);
 }
};

// Implement draw
Label.prototype.draw = function() {
 var projection = this.getProjection();
 var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

 var div = this.div_;
 div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
 div.style.top = position.y + 'px';
 div.style.display = 'block';

 this.span_.innerHTML = this.get('text').toString();
};
```

**Usage**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>
      Label Overlay Example
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="label.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var marker;


      function initialize() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100);


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: latLng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });


        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          draggable: true,
          zIndex: 1,
          map: map,
          optimized: false
        });


        var label = new Label({
          map: map
        });
        label.bindTo('position', marker);
        label.bindTo('text', marker, 'position');
        label.bindTo('visible', marker);
        label.bindTo('clickable', marker);
        label.bindTo('zIndex', marker);


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { alert('Marker has been clicked'); })
        google.maps.event.addListener(label, 'click', function() { alert('Label has been clicked'); })
      }


      function showHideMarker() {
        marker.setVisible(!marker.getVisible());
      }


      function pinUnpinMarker() {
        var draggable = marker.getDraggable();
        marker.setDraggable(!draggable);
        marker.setClickable(!draggable);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 200px; width: 200px"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="showHideMarker();">Show/Hide Marker</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="pinUnpinMarker();">Pin/Unpin Marker</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the function Label different from the default google one? If so, how do I change this?

I am currently trying to apply your label snippet from the second block of code to my own, but I am not getting any labels to show up.

Comment: The Label class is a custom class that is not part of the API. In the second snippet above there is a reference to label.js which is where the first code snippet resides. You might need to post some code so we can see what is happening.

Comment: You appear to have MarkerWithTag.prototype.onRemove and draw twice in your javascript, only need the functions once.