# Google Maps API v3 - Different markers/labels on different zoom levels

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was wondering if it is possible that Google has a feature to view different markers on different zoom levels.

For example, on zoom level 1, I want one marker over China with the label saying "5". And as the user zooms in, lets say on zoom level 4, I want the previous marker and label to disappear. And I want to have 5 new markers/labels, each on a different city in China all saying "1". Thus China will say a number and all the cities in China will say numbers adding up to China's number.

The key concept I am trying to figure out here is how to hide markers and labels based on zoom levels. A constraint for me is that I am living in China currently where google is censored, so a lot of online documents are censored for me, including many of google's documentations.

Here is my code thus far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>TM China</title> 
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
   .labels {
     color: red;
     background-color: white;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 60px;     
     border: 2px solid black;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDV0lcdK7C2GHbQAmdkBID70Uppuf-D030&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('7 m(a){2.3=a;2.8=V.1E("1u");2.8.4.C="I: 1m; J: 1g;";2.k=V.1E("1u");2.k.4.C=2.8.4.C}m.l=E 6.5.22();m.l.1Y=7(){n c=2;n h=t;n f=t;n j;n b;n d,K;n i;n g=7(e){p(e.1v){e.1v()}e.2b=u;p(e.1t){e.1t()}};2.1s().24.G(2.8);2.1s().20.G(2.k);2.11=[6.5.9.w(V,"1o",7(a){p(f){a.s=j;i=u;6.5.9.r(c.3,"1n",a)}h=t;6.5.9.r(c.3,"1o",a)}),6.5.9.o(c.3.1P(),"1N",7(a){p(h&&c.3.1M()){a.s=E 6.5.1J(a.s.U()-d,a.s.T()-K);j=a.s;p(f){6.5.9.r(c.3,"1i",a)}F{d=a.s.U()-c.3.Z().U();K=a.s.T()-c.3.Z().T();6.5.9.r(c.3,"1e",a)}}}),6.5.9.w(2.k,"1d",7(e){c.k.4.1c="2i";6.5.9.r(c.3,"1d",e)}),6.5.9.w(2.k,"1D",7(e){c.k.4.1c=c.3.2g();6.5.9.r(c.3,"1D",e)}),6.5.9.w(2.k,"1C",7(e){p(i){i=t}F{g(e);6.5.9.r(c.3,"1C",e)}}),6.5.9.w(2.k,"1A",7(e){g(e);6.5.9.r(c.3,"1A",e)}),6.5.9.w(2.k,"1z",7(e){h=u;f=t;d=0;K=0;g(e);6.5.9.r(c.3,"1z",e)}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"1e",7(a){f=u;b=c.3.1b()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"1i",7(a){c.3.O(a.s);c.3.D(2a)}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"1n",7(a){f=t;c.3.D(b)}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"29",7(){c.O()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"28",7(){c.D()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"27",7(){c.N()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"26",7(){c.N()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"25",7(){c.16()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"23",7(){c.15()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"21",7(){c.13()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"1Z",7(){c.L()}),6.5.9.o(2.3,"1X",7(){c.L()})]};m.l.1W=7(){n i;2.8.1r.1q(2.8);2.k.1r.1q(2.k);1p(i=0;i<2.11.1V;i++){6.5.9.1U(2.11[i])}};m.l.1T=7(){2.15();2.16();2.L()};m.l.15=7(){n a=2.3.z("Y");p(H a.1S==="P"){2.8.W=a;2.k.W=2.8.W}F{2.8.G(a);a=a.1R(u);2.k.G(a)}};m.l.16=7(){2.k.1Q=2.3.1O()||""};m.l.L=7(){n i,q;2.8.S=2.3.z("R");2.k.S=2.8.S;2.8.4.C="";2.k.4.C="";q=2.3.z("q");1p(i 1L q){p(q.1K(i)){2.8.4[i]=q[i];2.k.4[i]=q[i]}}2.1l()};m.l.1l=7(){2.8.4.I="1m";2.8.4.J="1g";p(H 2.8.4.B!=="P"){2.8.4.1k="1j(B="+(2.8.4.B*1I)+")"}2.k.4.I=2.8.4.I;2.k.4.J=2.8.4.J;2.k.4.B=0.1H;2.k.4.1k="1j(B=1)";2.13();2.O();2.N()};m.l.13=7(){n a=2.3.z("X");2.8.4.1h=-a.x+"v";2.8.4.1f=-a.y+"v";2.k.4.1h=-a.x+"v";2.k.4.1f=-a.y+"v"};m.l.O=7(){n a=2.1G().1F(2.3.Z());2.8.4.12=a.x+"v";2.8.4.M=a.y+"v";2.k.4.12=2.8.4.12;2.k.4.M=2.8.4.M;2.D()};m.l.D=7(){n a=(2.3.z("14")?-1:+1);p(H 2.3.1b()==="P"){2.8.4.A=2h(2.8.4.M,10)+a;2.k.4.A=2.8.4.A}F{2.8.4.A=2.3.1b()+a;2.k.4.A=2.8.4.A}};m.l.N=7(){p(2.3.z("1a")){2.8.4.Q=2.3.2f()?"2e":"1B"}F{2.8.4.Q="1B"}2.k.4.Q=2.8.4.Q};7 19(a){a=a||{};a.Y=a.Y||"";a.X=a.X||E 6.5.2d(0,0);a.R=a.R||"2c";a.q=a.q||{};a.14=a.14||t;p(H a.1a==="P"){a.1a=u}2.1y=E m(2);6.5.18.1x(2,1w)}19.l=E 6.5.18();19.l.17=7(a){6.5.18.l.17.1x(2,1w);2.1y.17(a)};',62,143,'||this|marker_|style|maps|google|function|labelDiv_|event|||||||||||eventDiv_|prototype|MarkerLabel_|var|addListener|if|labelStyle|trigger|latLng|false|true|px|addDomListener|||get|zIndex|opacity|cssText|setZIndex|new|else|appendChild|typeof|position|overflow|cLngOffset|setStyles|top|setVisible|setPosition|undefined|display|labelClass|className|lng|lat|document|innerHTML|labelAnchor|labelContent|getPosition||listeners_|left|setAnchor|labelInBackground|setContent|setTitle|setMap|Marker|MarkerWithLabel|labelVisible|getZIndex|cursor|mouseover|dragstart|marginTop|hidden|marginLeft|drag|alpha|filter|setMandatoryStyles|absolute|dragend|mouseup|for|removeChild|parentNode|getPanes|stopPropagation|div|preventDefault|arguments|apply|label|mousedown|dblclick|none|click|mouseout|createElement|fromLatLngToDivPixel|getProjection|01|100|LatLng|hasOwnProperty|in|getDraggable|mousemove|getTitle|getMap|title|cloneNode|nodeType|draw|removeListener|length|onRemove|labelstyle_changed|onAdd|labelclass_changed|overlayMouseTarget|labelanchor_changed|OverlayView|labelcontent_changed|overlayImage|title_changed|labelvisible_changed|visible_changed|zindex_changed|position_changed|1000000|cancelBubble|markerLabels|Point|block|getVisible|getCursor|parseInt|pointer'.split('|'),0,{}))
    var map;
    var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(35, 105), zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };



    var locations = [
                     ['Hong Kong', 22.39, 114.10, 1885],
                     ['Shanghai', 31.232, 121.47, 5885],
                     ['Beijing', 39.88, 116.40, 6426],
                     ['Guangzhou', 23.129, 113.264, 4067],
                     ['Shenzhen', 22.54, 114.05, 3089],
                     ['Hangzhou', 30.27, 120.15, 954]
                   ];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var i;
    /*
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      } */

    function myMarker(options) {
        if(!options.labelAnchor) {
          options.labelAnchor = new google.maps.Point(30, 50);
        }
        if(!options.labelClass) {
          options.labelClass = "labels";
        }
        options.map = map;

        return new MarkerWithLabel(options);
      }

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          draggable: false,
          map: map,
          labelContent: locations[i][3],
          labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
          labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
          labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}

        });
        }
        /*
        var marker2 = new myMarker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(20,20),
            draggable: true,
            labelContent: "second"
          });
 */
        }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:85%; height:85%"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

EDIT

I have been trying to experiment with the MarkerManager, but I can't get the markers to create successfully on different zoom levels.

First, I changed my default zoom level to 1, and then I changed my code to what is shown below.

```
function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
   /* for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      draggable: false,
      map: map,
      labelContent: locations[i][3],
      labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
      labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
      labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}

    });
    } */
    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){
        setupMarkers();
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
    }

function createCityMarkers() {


    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          draggable: false,
          map: map,
          labelContent: locations[i][3],
          labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
          labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
          labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}

        });
        }
}

function setupMarkers() {
    mgr = new MarkerManager(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function(){
          mgr.addMarkers(createCityMarkers(), 4);

          mgr.refresh();
      });
}
```

I have also tried applying the source code of this link as well, but nothing is working out. And when I copy the source code directly to my computer and replace all the icons with markers, the markers still don't appear. I can't seem to figure how to make markers appear using the marker Manager.
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/examples/weather_map.html

Comment: I have also tried using a batch procedure to create the labels when zoomed in, but that isn't working for me.

Comment: I am down to the point where I just have a map, a markermanager, and I add 1 marker. This does not even work ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The real reason why my program was failing was because of the Marker Manager, which doesn't work with my Markers with Labels.

There was actually a much simpler approach, however, to fulfill my needs.

```
function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        getMarkers();
        google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function () {
             if (map.getZoom() >= 3) showMarkers();
             if (map.getZoom() <= 2) eraseMarkers();

            });

    }

    function eraseMarkers() {
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
            marker[i].setVisible(false);
        }

      }

    function showMarkers() {
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
            marker[i].setVisible(true);
        }

      }

    function getMarkers() {
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
            marker[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
              draggable: false,
              map: map,
              labelContent: locations[i][3],
              labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
              labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
              labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
            });


            }
        eraseMarkers();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like thing you are trying to make is called Marker Clustering.

Here you are lots of official google exmamples https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers  written on native javascript

http://gmap3.net/examples/clustering.html - using jQuery library.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: In your first given link, the feature that I need to use is called Marker Manager. The difference between their use and my use is that they make each marker into an icon whereas I am using a marker with a label. The problem I am having is that I can't get Marker Manager to add/remove markers based on zoom level, even when I practically copied code and deleted all the icon related stuff. I make my own markers and try to use the function mgr.addMarker() but I get no results .

Comment: I under conceptually how to create Marker clustering with Markers/Icons, but everytime I try to apply it to my own code, I get no results. I think it has something to with the syntax, but I dont know what exactly is wrong since all I changed from Google's example was addMarkers() to addMarker() as well as create my own marker. Another thing that has me puzzled is that the Marker Manager page specify that addMarker(s) has 3 parameters, but the google source uses only 2. Regardless, I've tried and mixed so many variations of the code and am just staring dumbfoundedly at my screen.

Comment: Actually I am almost certain I realized what was wrong. I was using Marker Manager supplied by the Google API v3, however, I edited the markers to allow labels. And now Marker Manager is not compatible with my program.