# How to add label to each marker when using Clusterer API in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps API v3 marker with label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043587/google-maps-api-v3-marker-with-label)

I used Google Maps Clusterer API to show more than 100 markers on map.The marker lat,lon values are added in array and passed as parameter to Clusterer API. I want to add a label(like time) for each marker. How to add label to each marker when using Clusterer API.

**My Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var wifimaplocation = [
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub', 53.410133,-2.980967, 4],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 2', 53.410581,-2.98513, 5],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 3', 53.410341,-2.986254, 3],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (L1 6ER)', 53.408816,-2.983669, 2],
                      ['Yates Bros Wine Lodge', 53.407319,-2.98397, 1],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 4', 53.408373,-2.982217, 6],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 5', 53.408926,-2.983751, 7],
                      ['Liverpool Marriot Hotel',53.408926,-2.983751, 8],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (L1 1 St Johns Lane', 53.408563,-2.982344, 9],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (L1 1 Roe St)', 53.407407,-2.981337, 10],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 6', 53.40701,-2.981944, 11],
                      ['McDonald&#39s St Johns Precinct', 53.407121,-2.980573, 12],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 7', 53.406705,-2.980839, 13],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 8', 53.406859,-2.980066, 14],
                      ['Network Rail - Liverpool Lime Street', 53.408688,-2.9788, 15],
                      ['Wetherspoons', 53.405942,-2.979522, 16],
                      ['Crown', 53.406484,-2.978754, 17],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 9', 53.406574,-2.978513, 18],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 10', 53.406574,-2.978513, 19],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 11', 53.406488,-2.978749, 20],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (L3 5 Bolton St)', 53.405898,-2.97773, 21],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 12', 53.408026,-2.977398, 22],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Skelhorne St)', 53.416157,-2.988889, 23],
                      ['McDonald&#39s (Ranelagh Street)', 53.404594,-2.977877, 24],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Renshaw St)', 53.404639,-2.977296, 25],
                      ['Wetherspoons', 53.405183,-2.980989, 26],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 13', 53.405339,-2.979956, 27],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 14', 53.404869,-2.97993, 28],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 15', 53.403862,-2.979275, 29],
                      ['Brew Tea Bar', 53.403862,-2.979275, 30],
                      ['Starbucks Coffee', 53.404054,-2.980643, 31],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 16', 53.404054,-2.980643, 32],
                      ['Office (Holmes Building Wood Street)', 53.404223,-2.981673, 33],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 17', 53.403512,-2.980543, 34],
                      ['Djandos-Riff', 53.403512,-2.980543, 35],
                      ['Bar Liverpool Ltd', 53.403512,-2.980543, 36],
                      ['O Neills', 53.404174,-2.981809, 37],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 18', 53.405538,-2.98094, 38],
                      ['Currys/PC World', 53.404789,-2.982451, 39],
                      ['BT Pay Phone (Church Street)', 53.405506,-2.982687, 40],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 19', 53.406759,-2.98384, 41],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 20', 53.406686,-2.984221, 42],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 21', 53.406775,-2.98454, 43],
                      ['Cafe Nero', 53.407034,-2.98483, 44],
                      ['Ice', 53.406795,-2.98491, 45],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 22', 53.406142,-2.984355, 46],
                      ['WiFi Pod Office', 53.402954,-2.984422, 47],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 23', 53.403424,-2.984184, 48],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 24', 53.404203,-2.984097, 49],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 25', 53.404697,-2.985109, 50],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 26', 53.403798,-2.985541, 51],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 27',53.406863,-2.98583, 52],
                      ['McDonalds', 53.405218,-2.986485, 53],
                      ['WELKIN (Wetherspoons)', 53.405998,-2.985895, 54],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 28', 53.405237,-2.98648, 55],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 29', 53.405741,-2.986495, 56],
                      ['1Pco Lord Street Liverpool', 53.405183,-2.98649, 57],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 30', 53.405132,-2.987064, 58],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 31', 53.403868,-2.987311, 59],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 32', 53.403894,-2.98648, 60],
                      ['Liverpool Moat House', 53.401345,-2.985981, 61],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Paradise Street)', 53.401345,-2.985981, 62],
                      ['Starbucks 2', 53.402583,-2.986039, 63],
                      ['John Lewis', 53.402963,-2.986796, 64],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 33', 53.402986,-2.98442, 65],
                      ['Cafe Nero', 53.404462,-2.984958, 66],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 34', 53.406296,-2.99516, 67],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 35', 53.404654,-2.991283, 68],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (James Street)', 53.404654,-2.991283, 69],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 36', 53.405285,-2.99319, 70],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 37', 53.405608,-2.99139, 71],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 38', 53.405682,-2.991801, 72],
                      ['Brunswick Street', 53.40619,-2.992869, 73],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Brunswick Street)', 53.40619,-2.992869, 74],
                      ['Heywood House Hotel', 53.406695,-2.988615, 75],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 39', 53.406657,-2.990288, 76],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 40', 53.408013,-2.988277, 77],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 41', 53.408262,-2.98766, 78],
                      ['Premier Inn - Liverpool City Centre', 53.409174,-2.988051, 79],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 42', 53.409295,-2.987504, 80],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 43', 53.409577,-2.988051, 81],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 44', 53.409922,-2.987174, 82],
                      ['Liverpool - Hatton Garden / Tithebarn Street', 53.410632,-2.987276, 83],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 45', 53.410302,-2.98627, 84],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage - Liverpool (Hatton Garden)', 53.410302,-2.98627, 85],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 46', 53.410993,-2.986823, 86],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 47', 53.410542,-2.985216, 87],
                      ['Brunswick Vaults', 53.410376,-2.989443, 88],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 48', 53.410168,-2.98884, 89],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 49', 53.410389,-2.989615, 90],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 50', 53.408943,-2.990245, 91],
                      ['Railway', 53.408969,-2.990422, 92],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 51', 53.408787,-2.991678, 93],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 52', 53.408774,-2.994178, 94],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 53', 53.405682,-2.978199, 95],
                      ['Brew Tea Bar', 53.410159,-2.993776, 96],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 54', 53.410159,-2.993776, 97],
                      ['Cross Keys Public House', 53.409916,-2.993743, 98],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 55', 53.404812,-2.977298, 99],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 56', 53.404313,-2.976676, 100],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 57', 53.404697,-2.976611, 101],
                      ['stayCity Liverpool Mount Pleasant', 53.405183,-2.976314, 102],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 58', 53.405132,-2.976547, 103],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 59', 53.404275,-2.973522, 104],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 60', 53.404646,-2.972556, 105],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 61', 53.404518,-2.972341, 106],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 62', 53.404607,-2.971161, 107],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Brownlow Hill)', 53.403878,-2.97129, 108],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 63', 53.40526,-2.967471, 109],
                      ['Starbucks', 53.41154,-2.965196, 110],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 64', 53.410888,-2.967041, 111],
                      ['Liverpool - London Road', 53.409455,-2.97659, 112],
                      ['BT Openzone Business Hub 65', 53.41012,-2.969573, 113],
                      ['Wireless Outdoor Coverage (Pembroke Place)', 53.409238,-2.971505, 114]
                    ];
        /*var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);*/
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.410133,-2.980967);
            var options = {
              'zoom': 13,
              'center': center,
              'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

            var markers = [];
            console.log(wifimaplocation.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < wifimaplocation.length; i++) {
                console.log(wifimaplocation[i]);
                var mylocation=wifimaplocation[i];
              //var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,data.photos[i].longitude);
              var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mylocation[1], mylocation[2]);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
              markers.push(marker);
              console.log(i);
              mylocation=null;
            }

            var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 25};

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,mcOptions);
      }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add label to each marker in the same array where you add their lat long. I will try to put a sample on jsfiddle later but if you have your code on there it might be easier to help and add to it.