# Google Maps label

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have the following code that creates a marker on Google Maps:

```js
function initializeMap() {

    var lat = '-32.089608'; //Set your latitude.
    var lon = '115.933216'; //Set your longitude.

    var centerLon = lon - 0.0105;

    var myOptions = {
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, centerLon),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
 
    //Bind map to elemet with id map-canvas
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

I would like to add custom text to the pointer above the default marker but I cannot work out how to do it. At the moment it displays a small empty box above the default marker. (I am unable to post an example image due to lack of reputation points.

I am not very experienced with coding so any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need add `content` into your `infowindow`:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: 'abcxyz'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the standard library supports this.

But you can use the google maps utility library:

https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerWithLabel

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: myLatlng,
   map: map,
   draggable: true,
   raiseOnDrag: true,
   labelContent: "A",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelInBackground: false
 });
```

The basics about marker can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

[Google Maps API v3 marker with label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043587/google-maps-api-v3-marker-with-label)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to edit your marker click event function as below.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            infoWindow.setContent('abcdxyz'); // add this line to your existing code
        });
```

With this you can deal with multiple infoWindow for multiple markers.
Also if you want to display contents on mouseover, then you can use `title` property of marker like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat:lat, lng:lng},
            map: map,
            title: 'abcXYZ' // this will be displayed on marker mousover
        });
```